# PHP Fopen creates file but doesnt write

Tags: php, fopen

Here is my PHP code

```
$output = fopen('ftp://.io/inventory/'.$file_name, 'a');
fputcsv($output, array('ImportType','productCode','sku','locationCode','onHand'));
$newrow = array(0=>'AC',1=>'test',3=>'test2',4=>'test3',5=>'test4');
fputcsv($output,$newrow);
```

The file gets created but doesn't write any data to it.

I also tried changing the `fopen` parameter from `a` to `w`, it doesn't create the file at all.

777 permissions are all set for the directory.

More details:
when I upload files through Filezilla it works, my FTP settings in Filezilla is `Explicit FTP over TLS and the Transfer mode is set to Passive`

Comment: Does the code trow some errors?

Comment: @on8tom shows error Warning: fopen(): connect() failed: Connection timed out in

Comment: @user580950 So you're not connecting to the FTP server in the first place. There may be a firewall blocking it.

Comment: Do you have a pcap with the ftp attempt?

Comment: @on8tom sorry what is pcap?

Comment: it's a packet capture, used by e.g. tcpdump / tshar / wireshark.